# Boundaries of Sets

Tags: general-topology

This is a homework question from a Fractals & Chaos University course:

Find subsets $A,B \subset \Bbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) such that:

i) $\partial (\partial A)=\partial A$

ii)$\partial (\partial B)\subsetneq\partial B$

Attempt at solutions
i) take $A=\emptyset$ then $\partial\emptyset=\emptyset$ so $\partial(\partial\emptyset)=\partial\emptyset$

ii) I don't know how to start looking for a Set $B$. I have a feeling I can take $B$ as a subset of the rationals.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Have you looked at any examples besides the empty set?

Comment: Yes, you can take $B=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz No, my lecturer was only looking for one example. But, I guess, I could have $\Bbb{R}$ or maybe even any 'clopen' set.

Comment: Actually, I guess that your lecturer posed the problem to make you think about this. What I wanted to say is that if you determine $\mathfrak d\mathfrak d A$ for several sets $A$ you may get an idea of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the question:

One can take $A=\emptyset$ to satisfy i) and take $B=\mathbb Q$ (or any subset of the rationals) to satisfy ii).

With thanks to njguliyev and Carsten Schultz.